# Transparent PNG on video?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image, transparency

i am trying to put a transparent PNG image onto a video clip in the video editor. I have tried to mark them as alpha over, but it did not work. How do i do this?

Comment: Is the image you added above the movie strip in the sequence editor?

Comment: Yes, it is over.

Comment: When that happens I check the Transparent image using Gimp to make sure it does have an alpha layer.  Also if you lay the transparent image into the VSE all by itself and check the viewport, a checkered pattern should appear in the transparent areas when you press on 'render animation'. (Top left of window under 'render').  Another factor might be that when mixing, you're using the OpenGL render instead of Blender's internal version.